# How to bake an image texture with the same color as the Base Color

Tags: texture-baking, color-management

When I attempt to bake an image texture using a dark gray base color (r:0.125,g:0.125,b:0.125,a:1), the color of the texture is much lighter than what I expect. I'm using the following Bake settings

[image]

Here's a pic of the image texture. The color is (r:0.432,g:0.432,b:0.432,a:1).

[image]

When I change the Display Device settings from sRGB to None in the Bake's Color Management, the color of the image texture is closer to what I want. The color is (r:0.139,g:0.139,b:0.139,a:1).

[image]

My questions is how do I produce an image texture that has the same color as the color I set in the Base Color of the Principled BSDF?