# How to save default settings when saving an Image Texture

Tags: image, texture-baking, saving, settings

After baking a texture and before I save the texture from the "Image->Save As" interface, I check the "Save as Render" box, set the Color Management setting to "Override," and the Display Device to "None" (see pic below). My problem is when I attempt to save another baked texture, Blender resets the default settings, so I have to change the settings manually every time I save a texture. Is it possible to save the Image Texture settings (in Windows 10) to avoid manually setting them every time I save a texture?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings for saving an image from Image Editor are taken from Output settings set in the Properties Editor:

[image]

So if you change those, when you press Shift+Alt+S or go to Image->Save As in the Image Editor those will be default in the dialog that pops up.

Unfortunately for some reason this does not work with Color Management Override, so if you have to save a lot of images, you might want to temporarily change your Color Management settings for the scene in the Render tab, in Properties Editor.

Comment: Is there a "Save As Render" setting in the Output settings?

Comment: I believe you should set your display device to sRGB. If you need the texture to not go through color management(like normal maps), you need to set Color Space to Non-Color in the texture node when baking. Then you don't need to check "Save as Render". Save as Render forces to use scene's color management settings. I don't think switching display device to none in that case is a good idea in pretty much any situation... Am I missing something? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You answered two of my questions with one comment. See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292736/how-to-bake-an-image-texture-with-the-same-color-as-the-base-color).